# Sonos SMAPI unable to start playback of cloudQueue when receiving GET context and itemWindow

Tags: sonos

I am currently developing an API connection between my application, and Sonos Cloud API.
When initiating the loadCloudQueue command, some of tested players, will not start the playback of the
cloudQueue, but only the one item described in the loadCloudQueue command itself.

I really working blind, due to some of the players are able to start the cloudQueue playback, and some of them are now.

When testing the player, it is able to ask for the `GET / Context` and the `GET / itemWindow`.

- But it never starts.

Example of the GET / Context response:

```
queueVersion: 608124fb068ff506234390dd,
contextVersion: 608124fb068ff506234390dd,
container: { name: 'Handcrafted playlist for Ole ' },
reports: { sendUpdateAfterMillis: 100000, sendPlaybackActions: true },
playbackPolicies: {
    canSkip: true,
    limitedSkips: false,
    canSkipToItem: false,
    canSkipBack: false,
    canSeek: false,
    canRepeat: true,
    canRepeatOne: false,
    canCrossfade: true,
    canShuffle: false,
    showNNextTracks: 10,
    showNPreviousTracks: 10
  }
 }
```

And the itemWindow response:

```
1|app  | {
1|app  |   isExplicit: 'false',
1|app  |   reason: 'load',
1|app  |   itemId: '5f9d1e98e51a783b3bb741a8-2',
1|app  |   positionMillis: '2335',
1|app  |   queueVersion: '608124fb068ff506234390dd',
1|app  |   contextVersion: '608124fb068ff506234390dd',
1|app  |   previousWindowSize: '9',
1|app  |   upcomingWindowSize: '10'
1|app  | }
1|app  | {
1|app  |   includesBeginningOfQueue: true,
1|app  |   includesEndOfQueue: false,
1|app  |   queueVersion: 608124fb068ff506234390dd,
1|app  |   contextVersion: 608124fb068ff506234390dd,
1|app  |   items: [
1|app  |     {
1|app  |       itemId: '5f9d1e98e51a783b3bb741a8-2',
1|app  |       deleted: false,
1|app  |       track: [Object]
1|app  |     },
1|app  |     {
1|app  |       itemId: '5f9f16df0255876d60a379c2-3',
1|app  |       deleted: false,
1|app  |       track: [Object]
1|app  |     },
1|app  |     {
1|app  |       itemId: '5f9fd3606941737c38b52845-4',
1|app  |       deleted: false,
1|app  |       track: [Object]
1|app  |     },
1|app  |     {
1|app  |       itemId: '5f9fd741c790807608310700-5',
1|app  |       deleted: false,
1|app  |       track: [Object]
1|app  |     },
1|app  |     {
1|app  |       itemId: '5fc39512583fe814cc017df4-6',
1|app  |       deleted: false,
1|app  |       track: [Object]
1|app  |     },
1|app  |     {
1|app  |       itemId: '602b9707aa5ff30a5ce2e72a-7',
1|app  |       deleted: false,
1|app  |       track: [Object]
1|app  |     },
1|app  |     {
1|app  |       itemId: '603f977f64c25e20af3b2cb0-8',
1|app  |       deleted: false,
1|app  |       track: [Object]
1|app  |     },
1|app  |     {
1|app  |       itemId: '6040e7ca0c32a64babe1d19b-9',
1|app  |       deleted: false,
1|app  |       track: [Object]
1|app  |     },
1|app  |     {
1|app  |       itemId: '604fbefaf627431c25f670d2-10',
1|app  |       deleted: false,
1|app  |       track: [Object]
1|app  |     }
1|app  |   ]
1|app  | }
```

I really apreciate all the good advises I can get

Answer (score 1):

An example of a functional request & response for /context & /itemWindow:

- request to /context:

```
200 [06/01/21 5:03:14 pm] GET /v2.3/radio/myprefix%3a123456789012345678901234/context?queueVersion=&contextVersion= ReqToken- Bearer <authToken> ResToken- -
```

- response from /context:

```
{
  contextVersion: 'CV:00001',
  queueVersion: 'QV:00001',
  container: {
    type: 'trackList.program',
    name: 'my cool name',
    imageUrl: 'https://myartworkdomain/program_default.jpg',
    id: { objectId: 'myprefix:123456789012345678901234' }
  },
  playbackPolicies: {
    canSkip: true,
    limitedSkips: true,
    canSkipToItem: false,
    canSkipBack: false,
    canSeek: false,
    canCrossfade: true,
    canRepeat: true,
    canRepeatOne: false,
    canShuffle: false,
    pauseAtEndOfQueue: false,
    showNPreviousTracks: 0,
    showNNextTracks: 1
  },
  reports: { sendUpdateAfterMillis: 5000, periodicIntervalMillis: 30000 }
}
```

- request to /itemWindow:

```
200 [06/01/21 5:03:17 pm] GET /v2.3/radio/myprefix%3a123456789012345678901234/itemWindow?isExplicit=true&reason=load&itemId=&positionMillis=0&queueVersion=&contextVersion=CV%3a00001&previousWindowSize=9&upcomingWindowSize=10&heardItemId= ReqToken- Bearer <authToken> ResToken- -
```

- response from /itemWindow:

```
{
  contextVersion: 'CV:00001',
  queueVersion: 'QV:00001',
  items: [
    {
      id: 'C6RRZGXP',
      deleted: false,
      policies: { canSkip: true },
      track: {
        name: '<name>',
        album: { name: '<albumName>', artist: { name: '<artistName>' } },
        artist: { name: '<artistName>' },
        imageUrl: 'https://myartworkdomain.com/e24f71bf24f67a38eeeed6865d2bd582.jpeg',
        mediaUrl: 'https://mystreamdomain.com/e24f71bf24f67a38eeeed6865d2bd582.m4a',
        durationMillis: 123456,
        contentType: 'audio/aac'
      }
    },
    {
      id: 'FT46XQT3',
      deleted: false,
      policies: { canSkip: true },
      track: {
        name: '<name>',
        album: { name: '<albumName>', artist: { name: '<artistName>' } },
        artist: { name: '<artistName>' },
        imageUrl: 'https://myartworkdomain.com/0cff6be10e41a0beed35438b1e43bf8b.jpeg',
        mediaUrl: 'https://mystreamdomain.com/0cff6be10e41a0beed35438b1e43bf8b.m4a',
        durationMillis: 234567,
        contentType: 'audio/aac'
      }
    }
  ],
  limitedSkipsState: { skipsRemaining: 3, skipLimitReached: false },
  includesBeginningOfQueue: true,
  includesEndOfQueue: false
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Hi Loan, thank you so much for your reply! Indeed it worked, and I also found several other errors in my own code. Thank you for your reply, and your time! :-)

Comment: please accept the comment as answer if you may @KasperHollaender thanks in advance!